The button in Unity becomes unclickable after one use
So,basically I started to create my first game in unity 2022.3.36f1 and I started a new project. The only thing I wanted to start with was just using a "New game" button to switch from scene Menu to the scene MainGame. I created a simple menu, and when I press "New game", the scene changes, ok. Then I do the same in MainGame by pressing "Back", everything is ok again. But when I change to MainGame the second time, the button "Back" just can't be clicked, it can be moved etc, but not clicked (So it is active, and the tick interactable is turned on). I have only one little script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class ReloadScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public void ChangeScene(string Scene)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(Scene);
    }
}


This script is used on two empty objects in different scenes: "SceneManager1" and "SceneManager2" to use the function. Moreover, I saw that when the scene "MainGame" is loaded, this button become again unclickable.
I've tried reloading all the scenes, reloading the project, but nothing helps
P.S: Now it only works one time, and when the MainGame is loaded, the Menu scene dissapears from the hirearchy, and, while in playmode, I try drag it back, there is a message: InvalidOperationException: This cannot be used during play mode, please use SceneManager.LoadScene()/SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync() instead.
UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.OpenScene (System.String scenePath, UnityEditor.SceneManagement.OpenSceneMode mode) (at <2201ab87e660427c974282df3bb3cf36>:0)

Please edit your question to include the code of your script. Also you can't load scenes by dragging them in at runtime, that's where your error message is coming from - its unrelated. Maybe remove that part when editing your question as it might cause confusion.

As the error suggest, try using SceneManager.LoadScene() for loading/switching between scenes. Also make sure all the scenes you want to load are added in build settings.
For example:

make sure the name of the scene you give is the same as the name of your scene

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string sceneName; // set the variable value inside inspector
    // private string sceneName = "MainMenuScene"; // or like this

    // call this function on a button click to change the scene
    public void LoadScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
    }

    // or this way add the scene name inside the button inspector menu so you 
    // can have more buttons using the same function but each will load 
    // different scene depending on the name
    public void LoadScene(string name)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
    }
}


Have you checked your UI layers? Make sure your UI layer is always in the foreground while your main game is in the background. It could be it is not interactable because it is covered by something else.

I've checked everything in this theme, but nothing works
